# Just for first click the "img" class rotation is work but not for another clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just for first click the `img` class rotate to `180deg` and post class show, but i want for second click if rotate `180deg` change to `0deg` again and post class show.

Post class show is working but rotate just for first click work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".op-cl").click(function() {
        $(".post").toggle("slow", function() {

            if ($('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)')) {
                $('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
            } else if ($('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)')) {
                $('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)')` will always resolve to true because it returns the jQuery chaining for `$(".img")`. It sets the transform property and does not evaluate. See http://api.jquery.com/css/ for reference.

To fix this you could add a class to check if it is already rotated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".op-cl").click(function() {
        $(".post").toggle("slow", function() {
            if ($('.img').hasClass('rotated')) {
                $('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(0)');
                $('.img').removeClass('rotated')
            } else {
                $('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
                $('.img').addClass('rotated');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $(".op-cl").click(function() {
            var click=1;
            $(".post").toggle("slow", function() {

                if (click % 2 !=0) {
                    $('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
                } else if (click % 2 ==0) {
                    $('.img').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
                }
                click++;
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO better to use `toggle` when you want to toggle between two values :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".op-cl").click(function() {
        $('.img').toggle(function () {
            $("#user_button").css({transform: "rotate(0deg)"});
        }, function () {
            $("#user_button").css({transform: "rotate(180deg)"});
        });
    });
});
```

```css
img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='op-cl'>op-cl</button>
<br>
<img class='img' src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif' style='transform:rotate(0deg)'/>
```